# Directx11 Volumetric Render Positioning

Tags: directx-11, volume-rendering

So I have been looking into volumetric rendering using raycasting and i found an tutorial blog here http://graphicsrunner.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/volume-rendering-101.html

Now I managed to get this working I can render an image, but the problem is that I can only render the volume box at position 0,0,0 and a scale of 1,1,1

Obviously this is a problem as I want to use this method for particles that move around the screen

does anybody have any experience with this and would be able to help me out in any way

Thanks

Comment: Why can you only render a box at position (0,0,0) and scale(1,1,1). Some more information would be nice.

Comment: [Code would be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a picture, anything. What are you currently trying?